# how to play the video in iphone app from the server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I want to play the video in **iPhone App** from a server.

I have kept my video `ON FTP` and I am accessing it using: http://www.mysebsiteurl.com/Foldername/videofilename.m4v

But It's not working and if I am trying to play any **youtube** video it works.

So, can any one tell me any solution for it or provide some sample source code.

Comment: Hey! is ur prob solved.I want to exactly implement this

Comment: You say your video is on FTP and then you show an HTTP URL. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not play `.m4v` videos. It will play `.mp4` or `.mov` among other formats. The documentation for [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) lists them. Try renaming your video to `.mp4` and see if it works then. Also note that iOS will not play DRM protected video.

My code plays videos all of the time, in the `.mov` or `.mp4` formats. We download them into the Caches directory. You can get the path like this:

```
NSString *path = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0) {
    path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then play your movie using `MPMoviePlayerController`